# scikit-learn Imputer class - possible bug with median strategy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer to impute missing values using their median.
I've noticed that the first column in my data gets deleted, and for no good reason (the missing values are pretty sparse).
To clarify:

```
>>> X = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,np.nan], [7,8,9]])
>>> X
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   5.,  nan],
       [  7.,   8.,   9.]])
>>> Imputer(strategy='median').fit_transform(X)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\imputation.py:307: DeprecationWarning: using a boolean instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  median[np.ma.getmask(median_masked)] = np.nan
array([[ 2.,  3.],
       [ 5.,  6.],
       [ 8.,  9.]])
```

I'm using python2.7, sklearn version 0.14.1 with numpy 1.8.0.
I've tracked this to line 307 of the _dense_fit method of Imputation.py:

```
[304] median_masked = np.ma.median(masked_X, axis=axis)
[305] # Avoid the warning "Warning: converting a masked element to nan."
[306] median = np.ma.getdata(median_masked)
[307] median[np.ma.getmask(median_masked)] = np.nan
```

the `median_masked` variable in my case contains no np.nan-s - only float values. However it appears that `np.ma.getmask(median_masked)` returns `False` instead of the mask itself, which results in the first column median being converted to np.nan, and in downstream computation - it get's deleted. 
According to numpy [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.getmask.html#numpy.ma.getmask), this is actually an expected behavior, and np.ma.getmaskarray should be used instead.

I was wondering if my analysis is valid, and was hoping for advice on how to receive the correct behavior.

Thanks

Comment: What is `X`? Can you add a few lines to your code that generate an example that exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: `X` is a numpy array. I though my example was pretty clear but I've clarified this even further now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, and this was actually [fixed upstream](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/28997f63e5837fca1fea4f919fc924c41102c4ec). 0.15 (still to be released) should behave better.

Comment: Thanks. How would you bypass it? manually altering the source code?

Comment: @TalKremerman Either that or install the dev version. If you alter your installation, you might want to try to run the updated test suite for the `Imputer`, `sklearn/preprocessing/tests/test_imputation.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Some of you who visit this page may be experiencing a similar (but different) issue that can be caused when columns exist that are **entirely** composed of missing values.

While this is good reason to re-explore the data and build process, if you are automating something that could legitimately result in columns with nothing but `NaN` values, this code will remove those columns up front.

```
df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
```

This way if you need to map the array back to the associated source columns you retain the information that tells you what column belongs to what variable.

Comment: Thanks. This should be in `Imputer` documentation, but it's not.